# Install APK by adb to remote device - INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, adb

Windows 10.

I want to install my apk to device on remote machine.
My steps:

1. adb connect 112.xx.103.xx
2. adb devices

adb devices
List of devices attached

112.xx.103.xx:5555  device

3. adb install d:\my_folder\app-debug.apk

But I get error: **INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE**

```
[  0%] /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
[  1%] /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
[  1%] /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
...
[ 99%] /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
[ 99%] /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
d:\my_folder\app-debug.apk: 1 file pushed. 0.9 MB/s (13003641 bytes in 13.217s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

Comment: uninstall first the app and reinstall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is already installed, you must first uninstall your apk like this:

```
adb uninstall [package-name]
```

Then you need to open a shell on your android device with

```
adb shell
```

and disable package verifier with

```
settings put global package_verifier_enable 0
```

then you can try to install your app with

```
adb install d:\my_folder\app-debug.apk
```

Comment: 1. adb shell, 2. settings put global package_verifier_enable 0, 3. adb install my_package